# Run external spring boot application as part of an integration test

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing

Is it possible to run an external Spring boot application from an integration test? The basic idea is that I have a mock service that was developed for use in end to end testing and would like to be able to have the e2e integration test take care of starting up the service and shutting it down as part of the test.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you take a look at docker and the fabric8 maven plugin. This allows you to build container images that contain your application, start and stop instances of those containers as part of your integration test phases.